# Can i define 3 conditions in one condition line inside the automated flow's Trigger Condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

want to define these 3 "trigger conditions" inside a power automated flow:-

1. equals(triggerBody()?['IsDraft'],bool(0)).
2. equals(triggerBody()?['IsInProgressByWorkflow'],bool(1)).
3. equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/ActiveStatus/Value'], 'Active').

now i can create 3 conditions lines and define each condition inside one condition line, as follow:-

[image]

or i can define this statement inside one condition line:-

```
(

equals(triggerBody()?['IsDraft'],bool(0)),

equals(triggerBody()?['IsInProgressByWorkflow'],bool(1)),

equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/ActiveStatus/Value'], 'Active'))
```

so which approach we need to follow? and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can combine into one using an `and()` expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#and

Also, instead of using `bool()`, you can just use the words `true` and `false` ... whatever works for you though.

Comment: so the and operator can take 3 conditions and should not be only 2 expressions ? correct? Thanks

Comment: It's basically like Excel ...!